# Fixed position parent-child elements with another fixed element in between

Tags: html, css

I'm using a javascript library to create modal windows in my application.

I'm having a problem where there are 2 divs, A and B (A is parent of B) both position:fixed. Div A has z-index:1 and the Div B z-index:3.

I want another div, C, also with fixed position but external to these two, be in between them (with z-index:2), but it ends up on top of all. Apparently the child div(B) z-index  does not matter at all and always stays on bottom of div C..

I made a JSBIN with the sample here:

http://jsbin.com/koyasu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

This is just how `z-index` works. The parent div sets the layer for it and all of its children. Children who set a `z-index` will only be changing their layer inside that parent.

You'll have to restructure your DOM for this one, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed position always refers to the viewport, so you might as well take DIV "B" out of "A", getting three fixed elements on the same level. Then z-index can be applied more relieable.